# Dropdown is not working in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Dropdown is not working in Angular js . Actually i am doing editing this Category and SubCategory. This is my code here in this Category is selected but SubCategory is not selected why?
SubCategory is printed and alert out of the dropdown menu

I need to preselected the dropdown, the value corresponding from the database

this is my html code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Category</b></label>
        <select ng-model="selectedCategory" class="form-control" id="categories" ng-init="selectedCategory = null" ng-change="onCategoryChange(selectedCategory)"> 
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in categories | orderBy:'catName'| groupBy:'catName'">{{key}}</option>           
        </select>           
      </div>              
    </div>      

    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    <div class="row">     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>SubCategory</b></label> {{selectedSubCategory}}
        <select class="form-control" id="subcategories" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-disabled="!selectedCategory" 
         ng-options="categories.subCatName for categories in categories | filter: {catName:selectedCategory}" ng-change="getValue(selectedSubCategory)">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>  

       </select>
      </div>          
    </div>
```

This is my script.js

```
    var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory/"+$scope.product.catId);

    categoryPromise.success(function(data1, status1, headers1, config1) 
    {
        $scope.category=data1;


        $scope.selectedCategory=$scope.category.catName;
        $scope.selectedSubCategory=$scope.category.subCatName;
        //alert($scope.selectedSubCategory)


        //----------------------------------------------------

        var categoryPromiseGet = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");

        categoryPromiseGet.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            $scope.categories=data;

            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.categories,null,5))
            alert($scope.selectedSubCategory)

        }); 

        categoryPromiseGet.error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            alert("Error");
        });

        //----------------------------------------------------

    }); 

    categoryPromise.error(function(data1, status1, headers1, config1) 
    {
        alert("Error");
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a plnkr or codepen?

Comment: @user1655756 I am new in this i dont know how to use this.Please help me sir?

Comment: @user1655756 Please help me

Comment: Your question is not clear dude. Explain what happens and what should happen more clearly and remove useless code.